# Is this question still on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, needs-more-focus

I recently reviewed [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27427313/215552) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258422/comparison-between-stateless-on-google-code-and-windows-workflow), and was trying to decide if it was the answer I was having problems with or the question.

The question quite literally asks for "what the other .NET programmers out there are using," followed later in an edit by "Thoughts?"

It seems overly broad, and prone to the type of answers currently showing up. The question, and its self-answer are up-voted (31 & 38, both with no down-votes), so I presume someone found them helpful, but I'm not sure leaving this question open to more answers is going to help the community.

I've flagged the question as Too Broad, and voted to delete the answer as a comment not an answer, but I'm left wondering if that is the correct avenue.

Comment: *I'm left wondering if that is the correct avenue.* Yes

Comment: @Compass; Yes, that is the correct avenue or Yes, I am left wondering? ;) Just kidding...